# Azure Keyvault Secret with username and ssh key for SFTP

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I need to store a username and ssh file in keyvault to use to connect to a remote SFTP server.

I can create a secret with a username/password combo.  I can create a secret with the ssh keyfile.  I can't figure out how to create a secret with a username/ssh keyfile combination.  Can it be done?

Comment: How are you connecting to the remote sFTP server? Is it via Logic apps or Data factory? If yes, you can store the ssh file as a secret after converting it to base64 format. Have a look at this blog for more information https://medium.com/@anupamchand/generation-of-sftp-keys-and-load-to-keyvault-for-adf-or-logic-apps-37aa8760bfbc

Comment: We actually have a function app we've written to schedule file transfers between a large number of sources and destinations.  The majority of our FTP and SFTP processes currently use username/password combinations, but a number of our partners are converting to username/ssh key.

I am able to create a secret for the key file using:

az keyvault secret set --vault-name "KEYVAULT-NAME" --name "SECRET-NAME" --file "filename"

But I can't seem to get the username into the secret.  Each instance of our FA only calls one secret for the source and one for the destination.

Comment: You may need to do some changes to the code. You can change the code to read the Key vault twice, 1 for username and 1 for key file. Else convert the ssh file to a base64 format and prefix it with the "<username>-". Then in your code read this entire string as a secret, split it by the "-" delimiter and convert the 2nd half back into the original ssh file using base64 decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Anupam Chand` for suggesting the same point.

`Azure Key Vault` doesn't directly support storing a combination of a **username** and an **SSH key file** as a single secret, However, you can achieve this by storing them as two separate secrets in the `Key Vault` and then retrieving and combining them in your script by following steps.

**Store username in key vault**

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name "VKV" --name "Username" --value "azureuser"
```

**Store SSH key file in key vault**

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name "VKV" --name "SshKey" --file "/user/Venkatvm.pem"
```

**Result:**

[image]

`Retrieve` and `combine` the retrieved username and **SSH key** content in your script to connect the application.

```bash
   
    username=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name "VKV" --name "VMusername" --query "value" -o tsv)
    
    ssh_key=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name "VKV" --name "SshKeyFile" --query "value" -o tsv)
    
    vm_ip="172.178.91.148"
    
    echo "$ssh_key" > /user/private-key.pem
    chmod 400 /user/private-key.pem
    
    ssh -i /user/private-key.pem "$username@$vm_ip"
```

[image]

Reference:   [az keyvault secret set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-set)